# React Application Environment Variable Undefined after Deploying

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables

[image]

The Application is Deployed via Gitlab Kubernetes. After its deployed the env is undefined

[image]

Just want to know how do i use env in React like Next.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the React-dotenv : https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dotenv

Example code :

```
import React from "react";
import env from "react-dotenv";

export function MyComponent() {
  return <div>{env.MY_VARIBLE}</div>;
}
```

deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: test
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: test
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: test-image
      containers:
        - name: test
          image:test/image:v12
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          env:
          - name: MY_VARIBLE
            value: "hello world"
```

**Option 2**

Use **config.json** to store environment variables

**config.json**

```
{
  DATA: "$DATA",
  URL: "$URL"
}
```

code example

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import Config from "../config.json";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.hello.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  environment = Config.DATA;
  baseUrl = Config.URL;
}
```

Read more at : https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2021/03/04/making-environment-variables-accessible-in-front-end-containers#inject_the_environment_variables